# Смена содержимого страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

У меня такой вопрос.
Можно ли сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопку открывалась новая вкладка в браузере с содержимым, которое указано в *textarea*. Если да, то напишите как.
*Надеюсь, вы поняли вопрос ;)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у пользователя настроено, чтоб по умолчанию открывало в новой вкладке, то откроет, а если нет, то откроет в новом окне. [Тестируем тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/936krr7y/1/)

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var win = window.open('', '_blank');
    win.document.write('<html><head><title>Содержимое textarea</title>');
    win.document.write('</head><body >');
    win.document.write('<pre>' + $('textarea').val() + '</pre>');
    win.document.write('</body></html>');
    win.focus();
});
```